# Ceiling fan wired to gfi. Light kit wired to separate light power

Tags: wiring

Adding ceiling fan to garage. Power for fan is coming from gfi through door opener outlet. So fan can stay on without lights on. How to wire light kit though existing light circuit?

Comment: Some pictures of the circuits involved would be helpful.

Comment: Not enough information (yet?) to answer you

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please, with the breaker off of course? Also, how many white wires does your fan have coming out of it, and what make and model is it for that matter?